# Confusion with Spark streaming multiple input kafka dstreams

Tags: spark-streaming

I'm new to Spark Streaming. I don't know the difference between the codes below:

A:

```
 val kafkaDStreams = (1 to 3).map { i =>
      KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams,
        topicsMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
        .map(_._2)
 }
 ssc.union(kafkaDStreams).foreachRDD(......)
```

B:

```
val kafkaDStreams = (1 to 3).map { i =>
     KafkaUtils.createStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams,
            topicsMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
     .map(_._2).foreachRDD(......)
}
```

What differences between the 2 code samples when executed in Spark Streaming App. Any help? Thanks！

Answer (score 2):

I'll do this backwards, because it's probably easier to explain that way :-)

In the second example, you create three [DStreams](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams) via `(1 to 3).map { [...] createStream [...] }` and then call `foreachRDD` on them, so you have three separate sets of processing going on in parallel, so your `foreachRDD` function is called three times for every time period you set on your Spark streaming context - i.e. in the first time period, you'll get one call to `foreachRDD` for stream 1, one for stream 2 and one for stream 3.

In the first example, you create the same three DStreams, but then call `union` on them to produce just one DStream with the elements from all three. This means that you get just one call to your `foreachRDD` function for each time period, but the RDD, but it now contains the elements from *all* of stream 1, stream 2 and stream 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,Philip. As you say , in the second example there are three separate processes going on **in parallel** , then if the cluster resources are sufficient, the second code example will have better performance .Right? And what's the use cases for the two?